# How to silence output of the parted command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm in the process of creating some bash script, and I would need to silence the `parted` command in some use cases. The answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silence-output-in-a-bash-script) doesn't help.

Here's the piece of code I'm using:

```
parted -s $1 mklabel gpt &> /dev/null
```

And here's the output, no matter the output redirection:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# parted -s /dev/sda mklabel gpt &> /dev/null
 sda:
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Is there's any way, even a tricky one, to silence this command?

Comment: The link behind "this question" doesn't work

Comment: Corrected. Just a link to the "duplicate" question :)

Comment: @Pierre I don't know how `parted` works. Since you already redirect stdout and stderr, the only way I can think this can happen is when the output(or error) comes from the shell that's not part of the `parted` itself. You can try: `{ parted -s $1 mklabel gpt &> /dev/null ; } &>/dev/null` if that's the case.

Comment: @BlueMoon thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: @Pierre Other reason may be that your shell doesn't support `&>`. So you explicitly redirect them: `parted -s $1 mklabel gpt 2>&1 > /dev/null` or `{ parted -s $1 mklabel gpt 2>&1 > /dev/null ; } 2>&1 >/dev/null`

Comment: @BlueMoon Must be the parted command itself, I guess. The shell supports `&>`, and your idea doesn't work either.

Comment: You can't be doing what you think you are. If it appears on the terminal, then it seems to me it must be going to stdout or stderr. So the redirection of those isn't working. Can you check with a command other than parted that you are successfully redirecting stdout/stderr?

Comment: @Paul I just tested. `ls . &> /dev/null` returns nothing, so does `ls nonexistent &> /dev/null`. The redirection seems to work.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Unless parted is writing directly to the terminal, I can't see how the output is getting there...

Comment: This question hints that parted does require an actual terminal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770738/parted-mklabel-raises-an-error-through-python-subprocess

Comment: Try it this way `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Use strace to invoke your command and examine the system calls where the offending output occurs. It may be that you're running from the console and parted writes directly to the console device.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null.

parted -s $1 mklabel gpt 1>>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null

Comment: @Pierre what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the output "sda:" is not from parted, it's a kernel's print.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).